# SQLite: How to create a new table from another table when the columns are disparate but linked by one column

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, case, sql-insert

Say I have a new table like such where there is no values yet:

| key | uuid | dog | cat | deer | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

and i have a populated table like such where it has values that i want to correlate to the new empty table:

| key | uuid | format | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uuid1 | dog | hairy |
| 2 | uuid1 | cat | fluffy |
| 3 | uuid2 | dog | shaved |
| 4 | uuid3 | deer | smooth |

what i want to do is take each "format" from table 2 and create a new column in table 1 where "status" from table 2 is the value of the new "format" column in table one. Here is what i want the table to look like assuming the above tables are what im working with:

| key | uuid | dog | cat | deer | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uuid1 | hairy | fluffy | null | other value |
| 2 | uuid2 | shaved | null | null | other value |
| 3 | uuid3 | null | null | smooth | other value |

The extra tricky part is in table 2, uuid1 can have more or less "format" values than say uuid2 and visa versa continuing on to like 50k uuids so i need to fill the other columns with a null or falsey value

Is this possible or am I working with too ridiculous of data to make it happen?

Comment: this is called a "Pivot" and in this case "Dynamic Pivot" as you don't know all the possible `format` values ahead of time to hard-code into your pivot clause or case expressions. That being said, it's a terrible usecase for an RDBMS, and double so for sqlite where there is no `pivot` clause, and triple-so as the values you are pivoting are non-numeric. Personally I would do this transformation elsewhere, like in Python or what-have-you.

Comment: It sounds like you need pivot tables combined with an insert command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created the new table this means that you already know the possible values of the column `format`.
In this case you can use conditional aggregation to populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (uuid, dog, cat, deer)
SELECT uuid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN format = 'dog' THEN status END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN format = 'cat' THEN status END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN format = 'deer' THEN status END)
FROM table1
GROUP BY uuid;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ed4421fc2972da1124fa87593f664a61).